# little bar on modalview in iOS 13

Tags: ios13

Did anyone already discovered how to add this little 'button' when using modalviews in iOS 13?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5KnA.png

Answer (score 0):

it was done! with

`UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_orange"]];
    CGFloat width = 75.0;
    CGFloat height = 5.0;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - width / 2, 6, width, height); //change height and width accordingly
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];`